# Android MediaPlayer IllegalStateExceptoion when called pause()

Tags: android, media-player, illegalstateexception

I want to have two different background music loops playing depending on the state of the app. To do so I tried that code:

```
private void backgroundMusicPlayer() {
    if (gameMode == 0) {
        if (backgroundloop2 != null) {
            backgroundloop2.pause();
            backgroundloop2.stop();
            backgroundloop2.release();
            backgroundloop2 = null;
        }
        backgroundloop1 = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), R.raw.gameloop1);
        backgroundloop1.setLooping(true);
        backgroundloop1.start();
    }
    else {
        if (backgroundloop1 != null) {
            backgroundloop1.pause();
            backgroundloop1.stop();
            backgroundloop1.release();
            backgroundloop1 = null;
        }
        backgroundloop2 = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), R.raw.gameloop2);
        backgroundloop2.setLooping(true);
        backgroundloop2.start();
    }
}
```

But I just get errors:

> "MediaPlayer: start called in state 64" "MediaPlayer: pause called in
>   state 8" "Failed to open libwvm.so: dlopen failed: library "libwvm.so"
>   not found" "Media Player called in state 0, error (-38,0)"

How can I do it properly?

Comment: I don't know, arent u code missing a "player.prepare()" ?

Comment: Actually not. the create() method automatically calls the prepare() method.

Answer (score 0):

Why IllegalStateException in onPause()?

In Android Documentation for **onPause**:

> **IllegalStateException**
>   If the internal player engine has not been initialized.

In the document, you can see a maximum of media player methods would throw you IllegalStateException for some reason.

So use **try catch** for all of your media player operations.

Android recommends looking for Exceptions while using media player object.

> It is good programming practice to always look out for
>   IllegalArgumentException and IOException that may be thrown from the
>   overloaded setDataSource methods.

Comment: But what should I do in the catch method? Because it should have been initialized, the song is actually playing.

Comment: Well, it was a great idea to put the try catch blocks into the code. I rly dont know why I didnt. Anyways I get this now:

"ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: env->IsInstanceOf fails"
"MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0"

But the music is working.